# Trigger a pop-up message when a certain cell is filled

Tags: excel

I've got a Excel form, in which I want to trigger a pop-up message when the next issue occurs:
If the user puts a value (<>"") in cell A3, cell B3 shouldn't be able to be given a value anymore.
So the user can either fill in A3 or B3, leave both empty, but never fill in both.

I prefer a non-VBA solution, given issues with macro-enabled files with the users. I've been messing around with Data Validation (since there's the customizable pop-up error message), but haven't found a way to get this working.

Do you have any suggestions/solutions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data validation in `A3` and `B3` you can choose `Custom` and then a formula like:

```
=OR(ISBLANK(A3),ISBLANK(B3))
```

Depending on your detailed requirements, you may need to tweek the test (`=""` instead of `ISBLANK`) or use absolute refs (`$A$3`, `$B$3` instead of `A3`, `B3`).